# AWS Lambda not finding an environmental variable value

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm attempting my first AWS project using this project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZKJFKu49Dk&list=PLBJe2dFI4sguF2nU6Z3Od7BX8eALZN3mU&index=1. I'm trying to use a lambda function to take json data and turn it into a parquet table (at least... I think that's what I'm doing), so it's structured. I've got four enviromental key/value pairs, and for some my first one is not registering. Here's some more info:

Here's my code:

```
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
import os

# Temporary hard-coded AWS Settings; i.e. to be set as OS variable in Lambda
os_input_s3_cleansed_layer = os.environ['s3_cleansed_layer']
os_input_glue_catalog_db_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_db_name']
os_input_glue_catalog_table_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_table_name']
os_input_write_data_operation = os.environ['write_data_operation']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try: 
        # Creating dataframe from content
        df_raw = wr.s3.read_json('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key))
        
        # Extract required columns:
        df_step_1 = pd.json_normalize(df_raw['items'])
        
        # Write to S3
        wr_response = wr.s3.to_parquet(
            df=df_step_1,
            path=os_input_s3_cleansed_layer,
            dataset=True,
            database=os_input_glue_catalog_db_name,
            table=os_input_glue_catalog_table_name,
            mode=os_input_write_data_operation
        )
    
        return wr_response
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Here's an image of my configuration environmental variables (the first one, glue_catalog_db_name, and it's value don't seem to be registering):
[link to the environmental variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iehn.png)

And here's the error:
[pic of here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZqQo.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From that error message, it looks like it's getting the environment variable values just fine. It's printing the value of the environment variable in the log, so why would you think that was the issue? It's actually having trouble finding a database named `db_youtube_cleaned` in AWS Glue. Have you created that database in AWS Glue yet?

Comment: Hi Mark. I'm a total newbie... so I didn't know I have to actually create anything called db_youtube_cleaned before this.

Comment: YOU ROCK!!! Totally worked. So, is this what's happening: I have to create a glue database first in order for my key glue_catalog_table_name to automatically create the table cleaned_statistics_reference_data inside the new glue folder?

Comment: Yes, the Glue table couldn't be created until the database existed.